# jQuery - check for empty TDs and if all empty hide the parent TR

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'd like to check for empty TDs (classes a-h only) and if all are empty, then I'd like to hide the parent TR. The issues I'm running into are, my empty TDs contain " "  I'm not sure how to test for those?

http://jsfiddle.net/FeQ7h/1/

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="requirementRight">Requirement</td>
    <td class="a">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="b">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="c">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="d">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="e">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="f">NOT EMPTY</td>
    <td class="g">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="h">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="requirementRight">Requirement</td>
    <td class="a">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="b">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="c">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="d">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="e">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="f">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="g">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="h">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
```

​

```
if ( $('td.a:empty, td.b:empty, td.c:empty, td.d:empty, td.e:empty, td.f:empty, td.g:empty, td.h:empty') ) {
   // hide the parent tr
} ​
```

Comment: is there a particular reason you need to use classes a-h?

Comment: yes, because I'm doing some other styling based those.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"If Empty" is not clear, since in your example, they are filled with "nbsp". This is the reason why I made a function called isEmpty() so you can define your custom rules in there. Since you didn't want requirementRight, I put td:not(.requirementRight). This is not the correct way to do it.

The correct way to do it, would be to put a second class on a-h, such as

```
<tr>
    <td class="requirementRight">Requirement</td>
    <td class="checkempty a">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="checkempty b">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="checkempty c">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="checkempty d">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="checkempty e">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="checkempty f">NOT EMPTY</td>
    <td class="checkempty g">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="checkempty h">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
```

So we can call tr.find(tr.checkempty)..

Anyway, here's the code!

```
$("tr").each(function() {
  var trIsEmpty = true;
  var tr = $(this);

    tr.find("td:not(.requirementRight)").each(function() {
      td = $(this);

        if (isEmpty(td) === false)  {
         trIsEmpty = false;   
        }
    });

    if (trIsEmpty == true) {
         tr.hide();                       
    }
});

    function isEmpty(td) {
        if (td.text == '' || td.text() == ' ' || td.html() == '&nbsp;' || td.is(":not(:visible)")) {
            return true;
        }            

        return false;
    }
​
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/FeQ7h/7/

Comment: Why do you use an additional function instead of using trim()? http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/

Comment: @Jen-YaKovalev because OP is not clear about what is "empty". At the same time, it would permit OP to put custom rules.. But you're right, .trim() would have worked and is a more elegant solution.

Comment: @Aktee How can I also add in if one of the TDs is set to display:none?

Comment: you mean you want only visible TD or not visible TD? you can do this $("td:not(.requirementRight):visible"), this will only select visible td..

Comment: not really.  So everything you did above works great!  The problem I'm having is, I run some other JS to hide the TDs basically setting to display:none, so they actually contain text.  Is there anyway I can also test for empty and display:none?  Thank you so much!

Comment: Ohh sure modify the function isEmpty, add this in the condition:   || td.is(":not(:visible)"). I modified the answer.

Answer (score 4):

firstly, I'd suggest giving the TDs an additional class to distinguish the TDs whose contents are to be checked.  below, I used .et (emptyTest).

the following syntax might be slightly wrong, but it should give you the idea:

```
$("tr").each(function() {
  var nonEmpty = $(this).find("td.et").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().trim() != ""; //check the trimmed TD content - will make it ignore all white space
  });
  if (nonEmpty.length == 0) $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand what you did, but my first TD will always have text in.  I need to only test a-h.  I think that's an easy fix, no?

Comment: yup - updated with the suggestion to fix that (realised after I posted that first TD would have text)

Answer (score 4):

This is what you are looking for:

```
$(function(){
    $('tr').each(function(){
        var _hide = true;
        $(this).find('td:not(.requirementRight)').each(function(){
            if($(this).text().trim() != ''){
                _hide = false;
            }
        });

        if(_hide){
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
})
```

You check every row for content other than whitespace and hide the row if none was found.
have fun!
working example: http://jsfiddle.net/kvCXa/7/

Comment: you omitted `<td class="requirementRight">Requirement</td>`, so the sol is wrong

Comment: this is easily fixed with the :not() selector: http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

Answer (score 1):

Why not leave out the non-breaking spaces? I'm guessing they are there for styling purposes on empty TDs?

If so you can use this CSS to solve that issue:

```
table
{
    empty-cells: show;
}
```

Corrected CSS.

Comment: I tired that, not going to work for my issue.  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: OP wants to hide parent tr if tds with classes a to h are empty, that ain't going to solve it

Comment: What doesn't work? If you're cells are actually empty, the selectors you chose should work. (Note: I updated my post to use the correct empty-cells value.)

Comment: @Ankur, the real issue is how to get his selectors to work. Why won't my suggestion work?

Comment: @KevinBoucher you suggestion would hide the individual TDs if they are empty (I think) - whereas the OP wants to hide the TR if - and only if - ALL the TDs in the row are empty

Comment: @chimp Yes, I realize that, please see corrected CSS -- my point was why use the `&nbsp;`? Without them, his selectors would work -- and no need for an `.each` loop.

Comment: yeah it will work now, that comment was for previous answer, +1

Answer (score 1):

```
$('tr').each(function(){
  var emptyTdArray=$(this).find('td:not(:.requirementRight,:empty)').filter(function() {     
  return $(this).html()!= "&nbsp;";  
  });

  if(emptyTdArray.length==0)
  {
     $(this).hide();
  }
});
```