# Find if a table contains only spaces

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I'm trying to find if a table contains only spaces in each columns. Practically it's an empty table but with spaces. Is it possible with Javascript or jQuery?

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td> </td>
  <td> </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a clear question, try this :

```
$('td').filter(function(){
     return $(this).text().search(/^\s*$/) != -1;
}).doWhatYouWantWithThat()
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can

```
$("table tr td").text().trim()==""
```

OR

```
$("table tr td:empty")
```

And if you want to do something like hide a the table based on the `td` emptiness, etc, [refer to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12846330/jquery-check-for-empty-tds-and-if-all-empty-hide-the-parent-tr)

Another [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/YHgYJ/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `text()` and `trim()` combination, if the trim() give zero `length` and without trim the length of text is not zero it means table contains `spaces`.

```
if($('#tableId').text().length > 0 && $('#tableId').text().trim().length == 0)
{
      alert("Empty table with spaces.")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest:

```
var cells = $('td'),
    allCellsEmpty = cells.length == cells.filter(function(){
                                        return $.trim($(this).text()) == '';
                                    }).length;
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/XsyV2/1/).

To hide the `table`, if its child `td` elements have no content (other than white-sapce):

```
$('table').toggle(!allCellsEmpty);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/XsyV2/2/).

References:

- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
- [`jQuery.trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).